# Applying style in format of kendo numeric textbox

Tags: kendo-ui, textbox, format, currency

How can I change the color of the currency in my kendo numeric textbox in jquery? I used the standard code in creating a numeric textbox in kendo.

```
$("#currency").kendoNumericTextBox({
 format: "c",
});
```

For example I have $12.00 as value in my input element.
I just want to change the color of the $. Not the 12.00.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Because its kendo, it was simply setting a ClientTemplate before loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Apply css for "k-formatted-value" class textbox i.e. Currency value

Try something like this..

```
  var widget = $("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox().data("kendoNumericTextBox");
  widget.wrapper.find("input.k-formatted-value").css("color", "red");
```

Refer this link to achieve

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/numerictextbox/how-to/change-text-color

**Updated**:

We can do some tricks to change currency format colour change.

I did for normal textbox.
Refer [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygsLgway/).

For your requirement try something like this.

steps:
1. Create one span element

2. Create onchange event for the input

   $("#salary").kendoNumericTextBox({
                           change: onChange,
   });
3. Define the style change functionalities.

   function onChange() {
       ChangeColorFormat($('.k-formatted-value'));
   }

   function ChangeColorFormat(inp) {
       inp.style.color = 'transparent';
       var span = document.getElementById('back');
       span.innerHTML = inp.value.substr(0, 1) +
           "**" +
           inp.value.substr(1, 1) +
           "**" +
           inp.value.substr(2);
   }

Comment: Hi. I only want to change the color of the currency symbol. Not the numbers too. Is that possible?

Comment: From my analysis only currency format colour change is not possible.

Comment: So is it not possible to have multiple styling in single input tag?

Comment: No. I can't use span as a requirement because the inputs are dynamic and customizable too.

Comment: Without span or div which is not possible in my point of view.